# What does the "more" mean here?

Tags: sentence-meaning, adverbs

What does the "more" mean in the following sentence:

> HTTP is used to transport **more** the HTML, HTML from the browser to render the view.

The picture source:

[image: pics about the "more" in my question]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This seems to be a mistake. The [original documentation, from 2013](https://github.com/apache/struts-site/blob/6fc291a3de373cba3922c1daced5ee102fb82d37/content/xdoc/primer.xml#L151), reads:

> The World Wide Web was built over the Hypertext Transfer Protocol  [(HTTP)](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt?number=2616)
>   and the Hypertext Markup Language [(HTML).](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/) 
>   A User Agent, like a web browser, uses HTTP to request a HTML
>   document. The browser then formats and displays the document to its
>   user. HTTP is used to transport more than HTML, but HTML is the lingua
>   franca of the Web and web applications.

It was mangled badly in [this commit](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/struts/site/trunk/content/xdoc/primer.xml?r1=1521447&r2=1521446&pathrev=1521447). I'd suggest reporting a bug, and maybe submitting a patch to restore the original wording.

Comment: That's an atrocious commit (granted, it's a branch merge, so probably reflects multiple original changes, but still)